# Hiding Chrome bookmark text via extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get a start in programming by writing a Chrome extension similar to the [Smart Bookmarks Bar extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4072/) for Firefox. Java seems straightforward enough, and I can probably figure out the specifics of building an extension but I can't find out what commands I need to change the rendering of the bookmarks.

1)Does anyone know where I could find the relevant documentation?
2)Does anyone know of extensions that interact with bookmark rendering I could take a look at the source code of?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you can do with the bookmarks is listed in the API:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/bookmarks.html

*(and as someone said here on SO: java is related to javascript as a car is related to a carpet :] )*

Comment: Checked that before, those commands focus on modifying the bookmark directory, as opposed to the interface concerning the bookmarks.